# Selenium Grid Parallel Test Is Not Work Parallel

Tags: java, selenium, testing, parallel-processing, selenium-grid

Hello I have two node which names are `Node1` and `Node2` and I do this tests in one computer. My problem is `Node1` and `Node2` tests doesn't work same time so They are not parallel. Thus when `Node1` is finish after `Node2` test start but I don't want it , I want them start together.I have already tried `parallel="tests"` and `parallel="classes"` in the `TestNG.xml` file.

This is my `Node1.java` file:

```
package grid;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Node1 {
    WebDriver driver;
    String nodeUrl;
  @Test
  public void f() {
        try {
            //configuration
            nodeUrl= "http://192.168.56.1:5555/wd/hub";
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
            capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WIN10);
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeUrl), capabilities);

            //test scripts
            driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/");
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Today's Deals")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Gift Cards")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Today's Deals")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Gift Cards")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Today's Deals")).click();
        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {       
            e.printStackTrace();            
        }
  }
}
```

This is my `Node2.java` file :

```
package grid;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Node2 {    
    WebDriver driver;
    String nodeUrl;
  @Test
  public void f() {
        try {
            //configuration
            nodeUrl= "http://192.168.56.1:5555/wd/hub";
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
            capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WIN10);
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeUrl), capabilities);

            //test scripts
            driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {       
            e.printStackTrace();            
        }
  }
}
```

And this is my `TestNG.xml` file :

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Test Grid" parallel="tests">
    <test name="Test Node1">
        <classes>
            <class name="grid.Node1" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Test Node2">
        <classes>
            <class name="grid.Node2" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: <suite name="Test Grid" parallel="tests" thread-count="2"> add thred count

Comment: @AnkurSingh same problem contiune, It doesn't work.

Comment: which testng version you are using

Comment: @AnkurSingh the last version

Comment: @DijitalDünya you have to use `parallel="classes"`. try that

Comment: @SeniorPomidor I have already tried

Comment: how many chrome instances are running in your grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with below [`testNG`](http://testng.org/doc/).xml` file which worked for me.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test name="Test" parallel="classes" thread-count="2">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.github.parallel.Parallel1"/>
      <class name="com.github.parallel.Parallel2"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <suite name="Test Grid" parallel="classes" thread-count="2" >
        <test name="Test ALl" preserve-order="false">
            <classes>
                <class name="grid.Node1" />
            </classes>
            <classes>
                <class name="grid.Node2" />
            </classes>
        </test>
    </suite>
```

Comment: second line give this error : `The content of element type "test" must match "(method-selectors?,parameter*,groups?,packages?,classes?)".`

Comment: Change parallel="method" now run

Comment: but it is give this error : `The content of element type "test" must match "(method-selectors?,parameter*,groups?,packages?,classes?)".`

Comment: parallel="classes" try to play with parallel parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you move WebDriver field declaration into @Test method in both tests. it should work also using parallel="methods". Fields are not thread safe.

```
 @Test
public void f() {
    try {
        WebDriver driver;
        //configuration
        nodeUrl= "http://192.168.56.1:5555/wd/hub";
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
        capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WIN10);
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeUrl), capabilities);

        //test scripts
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```